# Picking a video which is not of type mov from gallery

Tags: swift, file, video, mp4

Picking a video which is not of type mov from gallery.

I have the following code, which works for videos which are taken from an iPhone. However if I have an image of type mov which I save to my phone and try to choose that, nothing happens. The app doesn't crash but didFinishPicking is not triggered. The app freezes and the cancel button does not work either.

code so far:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any])
{

    dismiss(animated: true)
    {
        if let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? NSString {


            if mediaType == kUTTypeImage, let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            {
                //do something
            }else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie
            {
                //do something else
            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateProgress()
                self.collection.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The delegate is set in viewDidLoad as:

iPicker.delegate = self

My ultimate aim is to support:

```
"zip","doc","msg", "jpg","jpeg","avi","pps", "gif", "png", "xls", "csv", "pdf", "txt", "xls", "ppt", "tiff", "tif", "dwg"
```